# How does realloc() reallocate the memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, realloc

How does `realloc()` reallocate the memory which was first allocated by `malloc()`?

I know that you need to use `malloc()` before you´re able to reallocate the memory, but I don´t understand how that really should work. What if a dynamic-memory object gets decreased in size by `realloc()`? Is this respective piece of the object just erased after the call to `realloc()`?

---

My Question is:

1. How does the `realloc()` function reallocate a dynamic-memory object created by `malloc()`?

   ---

Note: I did this Q&A because many beginners seem to be still confused about the issue of reallocating memory using `realloc()` despite already existing questions here on SO for that topic. They seem to be a little confusing for anyone who is new to the topic and still do not represent the whole behavior of `realloc()`. Therefore, and because the questions, IMHO, still do not quite fit the answer I´d want to give, I made my own Q&A.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: All citations in the following answer are quoted from the actual C standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), section 7.22.3.4.*

---

First, the synopsis for the `realloc()` function from ISO/IEC 9899:2018, Section 7.22.3:

```c
#include <stdlib.h> 
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

---

Despite its name, the `realloc()` function does not "*re*allocate" anything. `realloc()` is *not* modifying an extant object in memory. Instead, it does some sort of "create (new object) & copy the data" routine.

---

If `size` is not `0` and `ptr` either points to an object that was allocated by one of the memory management functions (not just `malloc()` only) or points to `NULL`, then `realloc()` *usually* creates a new object and copies the data from the old object into the new object.

*I do say *usually* because you can´t assume that a new object in memory is really allocated. You must always check whether or not it was allocated by checking whether the returned pointer points to `NULL`.

---

If the size of the new object is larger than the old object, the bytes of the new object that are beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values. If the new object is shorter than the old object, the values inside the difference between are thrown away. Every other value remains in the new object as it was in the old one.

> The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

---

After that, **if**:

- `ptr` is *not* a pointer to `NULL` **and** *is* a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, and the object this pointer is pointing to has not been deallocated before the call to `realloc()`,

  > If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size. Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function, the behavior is undefined.
- `size` is not `0`,

  > If size is zero and memory for the new object is not allocated, it is implementation-defined whether the old object is deallocated. If the old object is not deallocated, its value shall be unchanged.
- and a new object could really be allocated if `realloc()` did not return a pointer to `NULL`,

  > If size is nonzero and memory for the new object is not allocated, the old object is not deallocated

and really only if *all* of these premises are fulfilled, `realloc()` deallocates the memory of the old object and returns a pointer with the address of the new object in memory.

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`.

If `realloc()` returns a pointer to `NULL`, no new object is created and the old object remains unchanged at its address in memory.

---

Optionally, to make the "pseudo-reallocating" behavior almost perfect, it is possible that the new object, after the deallocation of the old object is done (if it happens), is allocated back at the same address in memory where the old object was stored.

> The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object has not been allocated.

In this case, there are logically two data copying processes in `realloc()`, one time into a buffer object and later back to the place of where the original old object was stored. The buffer object is deallocated after the execution of `realloc()`is completed.

---

The pointer of `ptr` which first is used for pointing to the old object should not be used for the returned pointer. If the call statement to `realloc()` looks like this:

```c
ptr = realloc(ptr,size);
```

then you usually have a memory leak if the reallocation fails because you just overwrote the pointer to the old memory with a null pointer.  If you don't have another pointer that points to it, you've leaked the memory.

Therefore, it is usually better to use a variant on:

```
void *new_space = realloc(ptr, new_size);
if (new_space == NULL)
{
     /* …handle out of memory condition… */
     /* ptr is still valid and points to the previously allocated data */
     return; /* Or otherwise do not continue to the following code */
}
ptr = new_space;
size = new_size;
```

Note that according to what I´ve said above, the address may be the same as before the call to `realloc()`.

---

To make sure that memory management is really happening that way, we can try this experiment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t length1 = 4;
    size_t length2 = 2;

    int *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*ptr1) * length1);
    if(ptr1 == NULL)
    {
         printf("The object could not be allocated!\n");
         return 1;
    }  

    printf("value (not address) of ptr1 before realloc(): %p\n", (void *)ptr1);

    ptr1 = realloc(ptr1,length2);

    if(ptr1 == NULL)
    {
         printf("No new object allocated. Old object remains!\n");
         return 1;
    }

    printf("value (not address) of ptr1 after realloc(): %p\n", (void *)ptr1);

    free(ptr1);

    return 0;
}
```

At my try it gave the output of:

```
value (not address) of ptr1 before realloc(): 0x1db4010
value (not address) of ptr1 after realloc(): 0x1db4010
```

So, the address stored in ptr1 after the use of `realloc()` is equivalent to before the call of it.

#### Additional Notes:

- `realloc()` acts as `malloc()` when `ptr` is a `NULL` pointer:

```c
int *ptr = NULL;
size_t length = 4;
ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(*ptr) * length);
```

shall have the same effect as,

```c
int *ptr;
size_t length = 4;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * length);
```

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size.

But, in my personal opinion, you should not first allocate dynamic storage by the use of `realloc()`. I recommend that you always use `malloc()` or another allocating memory management function instead. It may cause some difficulties to future readers.

---

- You should not use `realloc(ptr,0)` as substitution for `free(ptr)` to deallocate the dynamic memory because it is implementation-defined whether the old object is really deallocated or not.

> If size is zero and memory for the new object is not allocated, it is implementation-defined whether the old object is deallocated. If the old object is not deallocated, its value shall be unchanged.

Always use `free()` to deallocate a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: *"realloc() may act as malloc() when ptr is a NULL pointer [...] you should not first allocate dynamic storage by the use of realloc(). Always use malloc() instead"* — Well, not really true, `realloc()` is guaranteed to act exactly like `malloc()` when called with a `NULL` argument, as the manual page states. Doing `ptr = realloc(NULL, 0);` to initialize a pointer is totally valid and is pretty common. See the relevant code here: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#3158.

Comment: As per the `free()` behavior when called with size `0`, that is indeed implementation defined as can be seen in the source from the use of the feature macro `REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES`: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#3149

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I had thought a long time about that phrase, too. But at least, I´d decided to state it like that, because it may cause, that someone who encounter this behavior in any code, and do not know that it is permissible to actually allocate objects with `realloc()`, tries to seek for the relative initialization of this dynamic memory object with an apparently more appropriate function. So, I wrote that just for the sake of do not cause any unnecessary issues. Since the standard says its possible and permissible, anyone of course can do it like that. But I just do not recommend it.

Comment: I understand the objective, but you should word it differently. What you wrote is just plain wrong.

Comment: Yes, not throwing rocks, because you have done a good job on sussing out the various nuances of `malloc/realloc`, but initial allocation using `realloc` is fine. Nothing wrong with it at all. Granted, I get the gist of your thought that it is better form to allocate with `malloc/calloc` first before calling `realloc` (and it's probably easier for new C programmers to follow), but all that said, it doesn't make the choice of initial allocation with `realloc` bad, wrong, etc..  (good edit -- now it is clear)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are right, I´ve edited my answer.

Comment: Good edit. I'd suggest to reword *"realloc() may act as malloc()"* to *"realloc() acts as malloc()"* though.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I have included it in the text. Thank you.

Comment: Good job. I have a doubt, though, about this line *"In this case, there are happening two data copying processes in realloc()."*. Do you have any citation about this? I failed to find one in the standard draft.

Comment: `Doing ptr = realloc(NULL, 0); to initialize a pointer is totally valid and is pretty common` [n2464](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2464.pdf)