# How to fix realloc expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘sizeof’ error?

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I get the following error below after calling `realloc`

```
void* realloc(sizeof(char)100);
```

The Error:

> linex.c:23:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before
> ‘sizeof’

Please help. Thank you. :)

Comment: Where is the respective code?

Comment: @Hashbro54 Read a t last the description of the function realloc. Sometimes it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void realloc(sizeof(char)100);
```

Assuming you mean a call to the standard `realloc()` function (not a declaration of a custom `realloc()`) and you want to resize memory, this code is wrong regarding three points.

#### 1.

`realloc()` needs a pointer to memory allocated by a memory-management and not already freed as first argument.

This is the prototype/declaration for standard `realloc()` function:

```
void *realloc( void *ptr, size_t new_size );
```

Your `realloc()` call omits this pointer argument.

#### 2.

Don't specify the return type (here `void *`) when you want to call a function. With this you attempt to make a new declaration of the function `realloc()` and not a call.

If you tried to do some casting in here, this is also wrong. For an implicit cast, you need to surround the type to be casted to by parentheses like `(void *)`.

Note that in both cases the cast is redundant. With view on the cast of the return type, have a look at:

- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12139179)

#### 3.

At the size argument you need the `*` operator between `sizeof(char)` and `100`.

---

Use:

```
realloc( ptr, sizeof(char) * 100 );
```

---

Note that you also always should check the return value of memory-management functions whether an error occured or not:

```
char * ptr2 = realloc( ptr1, sizeof(char) * 100);
if ( ptr2 == NULL )
{
    fputs("Error at resizing the allocated memory!\n", stderr);
    // error routine.
}
```

The same you **always** should do for `malloc()`:

```
char * ptr1 = malloc( sizeof(char) * 50);
if ( ptr1 == NULL )
{
    fputs("Error at memory allocation!\n", stderr);
    // error routine.
}
```

---

Advanced lesson (You don't need to understand it at this point of time):

Note that in the case of `realloc()`, I use a different pointer to catch the return value of `realloc()`.

This is because `realloc()` may or may not return the same pointer passed as argument.

An unfortunately common but bad practice is to reassign the pointer passed as first argument by the return value of `realloc()`.

This is dangerous since the reference to the memory allocated first can then be lost if `realloc()` allocated another "replacement" memory but didn't erased the first.

Related:

- [Is it good coding practice to assign the address returned by realloc() to the same pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213123/12139179)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435175/12139179
- [How does realloc() reallocate the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59738833/12139179)

Comment: Hi there, 

So would this line make sense?

 void *realloc(void *dynamic, sizeof(char)*100);

Thanks.

Comment: @Hashbro54 You need to omit both `void *`s when you call want to call `realloc()`. This not a declaration for `realloc()` nor some kind of type casting.

Comment: Right, So I omitted the void *, now I have this code 

 realloc(dynamic, sizeof(char) *100);

But, I get this error:

linex.c:28:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Can you help, sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Hashbro54 A compiler can be designed to warn about anything it want to. Your compiler seems to be very attentive. I added something to the answer. This is why the compiler gives you this warning. You always should check the return value of memory-management functions.

Answer (score 1):

`void* realloc(sizeof(char)*100);` is a mishmash of declaring a function and calling it.

When we **declare** a function, we say what its return type is and what types its parameters are, as in `void *realloc(void *, size_t);`. We may also provide placeholder names for the parameters as helpful descriptions, as in `void *realloc(void *pointer, size_t size);`. (Parameter names are required when fully defining the function.)

When we **call** a function, we do not give type names for the return value or the parameters. We just give expressions that provide the argument values, as in `NewPointer = realloc(OldPointer, 100 * sizeof *NewPointer);`.

Sometimes type names may appear in or near a call to a function, but these are incidental and are not directly part of the function call. Examples are:

- `char *NewPointer = realloc(OldPointer, 100 * sizeof *NewPointer);`: This code has `char *` because it declares and defines `NewPointer`. Then `NewPointer` is initialized with the `realloc` call.
- `NewPointer = (char *) realloc(OldPointer, 100 * sizeof *NewPointer);`: This code has `(char *)` as a cast to convert the return value of `realloc` to a specific pointer type. This is not needed in C.
- `NewPointer = realloc(OldPointer, 100 * sizeof(char));`: This code has `char *` as an operand to `sizeof` to calculate the space needed. This is unnecessary because the size can be taken with `sizeof *NewPointer`, and that is generally preferable because it automatically adjusts to changes in the declaration of `NewPointer`, reducing the possibility that a bug might be introduced by changing the type in the declaration of `NewPointer` but overlooking the `sizeof` expression.

Comment: There was an edit made which shadowed another issue. Original code provided `void realloc(sizeof(char)100);` not `void realloc(sizeof(char)*100);`. I reverted this change in the question. Maybe you consider to take it into it? I also covered it already, so you don't need to. Just as a hint.